# The pull request is approved but not merged

Tags: github, pull-request

I have an active pull request, which **passed all required Github Actions checks** and has been **approved by the repo owner**. The problem is that it has been only approved, not merged. This isn't actually the first time I see this happened so I am curious. Is there any reason to wait before merging after approving the PR? Or the owner/reviewer with write access only forgot to merge it?

**Update:**

The branch was eventually merged. Is there a particular reason not to do that immediately?

[image]

Comment: Add your screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe one of the maintainers approved it but not the others and he waited for the "ok" from them before merging.